# convergence of $\arctan$ sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have a problem in Analysis:
Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\arctan(a_n)-\arctan(a)|=0$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|a_n-a|=0$.

I'm soluting the problems: "the topology induced by metric $\arctan$  is the same as the Euclidean topology".

Comment: Just apply the continuity of $\tan x$. The "topological gibberish" isn't a solution at all.

Comment: If you can prove your sentence about topologies, then your answer will be fine. But without any explanation, it proves nothing.